How I do it if I have updated the database then reflect it to the datagridview without reloading in VB.NET
I'M trying if I have updated the database then reflect it to the datagridview without reloading in VB.NET.
So it stays in the filter state in the datagridview.
It's also possible that the code I posted is still wrong
Please Guide Me.
Thanks
Private _criteriasBindingList As New SortableBindingList(Of Person)()
    Private bindingSource As BindingSource = Nothing
    Dim PersonService As New PersonService()

 Private Sub BtnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnUpdate.Click
        Try
 Dim people As List(Of Person) = TryCast(bindingSource.DataSource, List(Of Person))
            Dim bs = TryCast(bindingSource.DataSource, SortableBindingList(Of Person))
            For Each person As Person In people
                Dim Update = New Person With {
                                 .TIME = TXTTIME.Text,
                                 .OTHERS1 = TXTOTHERS1.Text,
                                 .OTHERS2 = TXTOTHERS2.Text,
                                 .NAMEPERSON = person.NAMEPERSON,
                                 .DATE = person.DATE
PersonService.UpdatePerson(Update)
 Next
   MessageBox.Show("Person In successfully updated")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Myapp", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        End Try
    End Sub

 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        loaddata()
    End Sub
    Private Sub loaddata()
        _criteriasBindingList = New SortableBindingList(Of Person)(CType(PersonService.GetPERSON(), IList(Of Person)))
        bindingSource = New BindingSource With {.DataSource = _criteriasBindingList}
        DataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource 'Set the data source.
    End Sub

    Private Sub myFilter(str1 As String, str2 As String)
        If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str1) AndAlso String.IsNullOrEmpty(str2)) Then
            bindingSource.DataSource = _criteriasBindingList
        ElseIf (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str1)) Then
            bindingSource.DataSource = _criteriasBindingList.Where(Function(c) c.DATE.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy").Contains(str2)).ToList()
        ElseIf (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str2)) Then
            bindingSource.DataSource = _criteriasBindingList.Where(Function(c) c.NAMEPERSON.ToLower().Contains(str1)).ToList()
        Else
            bindingSource.DataSource = _criteriasBindingList.Where(Function(c) c.NAMEPERSON.ToLower().Contains(str1) AndAlso c.DATE.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy").Contains(str2)).ToList()
        End If
    End Sub
 Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TXTNAME.KeyDown
        Dim str1 = TXTNAME.Text.Trim().ToLower()
        Dim str2 = TXTDATE.Text.Trim().ToLower()
        myFilter(str1, str2)
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox2_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TXTDATE.KeyDown
        Dim str1 = TXTNAME.Text.Trim().ToLower()
        Dim str2 = TXTDATE.Text.Trim().ToLower()
        myFilter(str1, str2)
    End Sub


@KarenPayne ,
Sorry to disturb you, because you can help me because I use your extension method  link  and link
But I forgot the link to the original extension method
